# Convert Python result in unicode instead of valid value

Tags: python

I am learning python. I would like to extract the data from teradata using PYODBC. I got the result in unicode instead of Valid values. Could someone help on this.

Result of code is

```
[(u'\u4445\u5f57\u5550\u4c42\u5f4e\u4449', 7)]
```

Expected is:

```
[EDW_PUBLN_ID,7]
```

---

```
pyodbc.pooling = False
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"../.."))
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),""))

try:
    tdconn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=oneview;UID=<userid>;PWD=<password>;QUIETMODE=YES;')
    tdconn.autocommit = True;
    curs=tdconn.cursor()
        logging.info("CONNECTIONS TO TERADATA AND REDSHIFT ESTABLISHED")
    print ""
    td_pg_edw = "select tbl_clmn_nm,onln_retntn_mths_dur from POVCTL.TDS_DATA_RETNTN_PLCY where TBL_SCHEMA_NM ='PEDW_MOBILE_TB' and TBL_NM = 'CAL_ACCT'"
    curs.execute(td_pg_edw)
    output1=curs.fetchall()
    print "execute started"
    List1 = list()
    output2 = output1
    print output2
    for row in output2:
        List1.append(row)
    print List1
    print "execute ended"
    curs.close()
    tdconn.close()

except Exception,e:
    print ("\n\n########################  UNABLE TO ESTABLISH CONNECTION ####################\n\n")
    logging.error("ERROR :   '%s' " %e)
```

Comment: Looks like it's reading the bytes as UTF-16LE instead of ASCII.

Comment: Okay. what change do i need to incorporate to get the expected result.

Comment: Not a clue. Might be one of the connection params.